# How to know the orientation of video in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an app in which I am taking a video from photo-library.
the video may be taken in portrait or in landscape mode.
I want to know the orientation of video so that based on that i can rotate stand play it in **MPMoviePlayerController**.
I did try it with **AVAssetImageGenerator** but its taking time and sometimes not generating image as required.